# Convert date to Unix in excel

Tags: excel

I have trouble in converting timestamps in Unix time in excel. I have a column of local time; it starts with

| Local Time |
| --- |
| 01.01.2014 00:00:00.000 GMT+0400 |
| 01.01.2014 00:01:00.000 GMT+0400 |

.. It goes on like this.

How do I convert it to Unix time?  I have tried using this formula:

```
=(A2-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400.
```

Comment: Remove the `GMT+0400` before converting the time.

Comment: I tried, but it is not working.

Comment: Probably the dot is not your date separator. You need to convert the time stamp into something Excel can understand as a date. Do a search of this forum for that process.

Comment: Then what would be your expected output?

Answer (score -1):

format the cell which will contain your answer to a number output and make decimals places 0